# How do I enable Compound TCP (CTCP)?

Tags: 12.10, networking

I would like to use [Compound TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_TCP) in Ubuntu.

The Wikipedia page says:

> In addition to Windows, CTCP was also ported to Linux [...] Since kernel version 2.6.17 the module has been incompatible and fails to compile due to kernel API changes.

Is there a newer implementation that works correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compound TCP by Microsoft is just one *implementation* of a congestion algorithm protocol. In Linux this has been discarded as you've already found, and it seems that [TCP Illinois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP-Illinois) was the direct successor, but not used that much any more.

Some work has been done to implement Illinois since 2.6.22: [LWN article: TCP Illinois preliminary version](http://lwn.net/Articles/229676/). It also seems still available in current versions: [`net/ipv4/tcp_illinois.c` in linux-stable tree](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob;f=net/ipv4/tcp_illinois.c;h=834857f3c8713e8d8b80ab7b4f413725ec0ca9b4;hb=HEAD).

[TCP New Reno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_avoidance_algorithm#TCP_New_Reno), another alternative based on [RFC3782](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3782) seems to be the most commonly used in Linux and completely integrated in the kernel. See also the manpage `tcp(7)`:

> ```
>   tcp_available_congestion_control (String; read-only; since Linux 2.4.20)
> ```

```
          Show  a list of the congestion-control algorithms that are registered.  This
          list is a limiting set for the list in tcp_allowed_congestion_control.  More
          congestion-control algorithms may be available as modules, but not loaded.
```

Check the ones available on your system:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control
```

and active:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control
```

Change the active one by writing to it (example `reno`):

```
echo reno | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_congestion_control
```

---

*Bottom line: You're probably already using a very modern and very efficient TCP congestion algorithm protocol just by using a recent Linux kernel.*

Answer (score 2):

As far as I could see it, it was removed from mainline kernel (see [git commit](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=commit;h=90ca9a2ff4d6b89b6939c3ece19f8fed1eecdbab)). According to a search within git it never came back. So the entry in Wikipedia is right. You have no chance to get it working (until you rewrite the code).